Environment variable LOGNAME or USER does not correspond to effective user id
I'm running an Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS server. The server hosts some Virtualbox virtual machines that I backup with a bash script on a daily basis. That works quite fine. The bash script also sends some emails when the backup worked, or I get an error message by email if it fails.
Recently I started to receive some emails from Cron Daemon stating the following:
WARNING: Environment variable LOGNAME or USER does not correspond to effective user id.
The subject shows me the script that apparently causes the issue: Cron <user@server> /home/user/buprod.sh
The script is via crontab as a normal user, not root. What makes is more puzzling is that I am backing up more than one virtual machine, but I get that warning message just from one script, not the others.
Do I have to worry about the warning message? And how can I avoid it in the first place?
EDIT (Provide more information as per the comment):
The crontab is found at var/spool/cron/crontabs/matth and has the following content:
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# m h  dom mon dow   command
SHELL=/bin/bash

04 2 * * 1 /home/matth/buproxy.sh
24 2 * * * /home/matth/buprod.sh

The script that causes the warning message is the buprod.sh and has the following content:
#!/bin/bash

# =============== Set your variables here ===============
MYMAIL="name@domain.com"
VMDIR="/home/matth/VirtualBox\ VMs/ERPNext\ Production/"
EXPORTDIR="/mnt/video/Backup/vmbackup/"
TEMPDIR="/home/matth/temp/"
VMTMPDIR="/home/matth/temp/ERPNext\ Production/"
LOGDIR="/home/matth/logs/"
LOGNAME="erpnextprod.log"
VM="ERPNext Production"
ERR="nothing"
SECONDS=0
STARTUP=1
COPY=1
# =======================================================
# No manual changes needed below this point
# =======================================================

LOGFILE="$LOGDIR$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%T")-$LOGNAME"

cdt=$(date)
echo "${cdt}: Backing up VM ${VM}" >> $LOGFILE

# Get the vm state
VMSTATE=$(vboxmanage showvminfo "$VM" --machinereadable | grep "VMState=" | cut -f 2 -d "=")
cdt=$(date)
echo "${cdt}: ${VM}'s state is: ${VMSTATE}." &>> $LOGFILE

# If the VM's state is running or paused, save its state
if [[ $VMSTATE == \"poweroff\" ]]; then
  # skip the wait
  cdt=$(date)
  echo "${cdt}: VM ${VM} is already powered off" &>> $LOGFILE
  STARTUP=0
else
  # Shut down the VM
  cdt=$(date)
  echo "${cdt}: Shutting down the VM ${VM}" &>> $LOGFILE
  vboxmanage controlvm "$VM" acpipowerbutton
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then ERR="shutting down"; fi
  # cdt=$(date)
  # echo "${cdt}: Waiting 120 seconds to let the VM ${VM} shut down" &>> $LOGFILE
  # sleep 60s
fi

max_wait=$((SECONDS+120))
cnt=1
# Check state of VM
VMSTATE=$(vboxmanage showvminfo "$VM" --machinereadable | grep "VMState=" | cut -f 2 -d "=")
# Wait a maximum of 120 seconds to avoid an infinite loop in case the VM can't be stopped
while [[ $VMSTATE != \"poweroff\" ]]
do
   cdt=$(date)
   echo "${cdt}: ${cnt} loop(s) waiting for the VM ${VM} to shut down. Current state is ${VMSTATE}" &>> $LOGFILE
   # Wait a few seconds before checking again
   sleep 10s
   # Checking state of VM again
   VMSTATE=$(vboxmanage showvminfo "$VM" --machinereadable | grep "VMState=" | cut -f 2 -d "=")
   cnt=$(( $cnt + 1 ))
   # If loop has taken more than 60 seconds, break it to avoid an infinite loop
   if [ $SECONDS -gt $max_wait ]; then break; fi
done

# Check if VM is now powered off
VMSTATE=$(vboxmanage showvminfo "$VM" --machinereadable | grep "VMState=" | cut -f 2 -d "=")
cdt=$(date)
echo "${cdt}: ${VM}'s state is: ${VMSTATE}." &>> $LOGFILE

if [[ $VMSTATE == \"poweroff\" ]]; then
   # First copy it to a local directory to have a faster copy
   eval cp -R "${VMDIR}" $TEMPDIR
#   eval cp -R "${VMDIR}" $EXPORTDIR
   cdt=$(date)
   echo "${cdt}: VM ${VM} has been copied from ${VMDIR} to ${TEMPDIR}" &>> $LOGFILE
else
   ERR="not powered off"
   cdt=$(date)
   echo "${cdt}: Not exporting because the VM ${VM} is not powered off." &>> $LOGFILE
   COPY=0
fi

if [[ $STARTUP == 1 ]]; then
   vboxmanage startvm "$VM" --type headless &>> $LOGFILE
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      ERR="starting up"
   else
      cdt=$(date)
      echo "${cdt}: VM is started up again" &>> $LOGFILE
   fi
fi

# Calculate duration
duration=$SECONDS
duration="Operation took $(($duration / 60)) minutes, $(($duration % 60)) seconds." &>> $LOGFILE

if [[ $COPY==1 ]]; then
   # Now copy off-machine
   eval cp -R "${VMTMPDIR}" $EXPORTDIR
   cdt=$(date)
   echo "${cdt}: VM ${VM} has been copied from ${VMTMPDIR} to ${EXPORTDIR}" &>> $LOGFILE
   eval rm -R "${VMTMPDIR}"
   cdt=$(date)
   echo "${cdt}: Temporary directory ${VMTMPDIR} has been deleted" &>> $LOGFILE
   # Calculate duration
   duration=$SECONDS
   duration="Operation including copy to NAS took $(($duration / 60)) minutes, $(($duration % 60)) seconds." &>> $LOGFI>
fi

# Notify the admin
if [ "$ERR" == "nothing" ]; then
  MAILSUBJECT="VM ${VM} succesfully backed up"
  MAILBODY="Virtual Machine ${VM} was succesfully backed up!"
  MAILBODY="$MAILBODY"$'\n'"$duration"
#  MAILBODY=$(echo $MAILBODY && cat $LOGFILE)
else
  MAILSUBJECT="Error $ERR VM ${VM}"
  MAILBODY="There was an error ${ERR} VM ${VM}."
  MAILBODY=$(echo $MAILBODY && cat $LOGFILE)
fi

# Send the mail
echo "$MAILBODY" | mail -s "$MAILSUBJECT" $MYMAIL

EDIT 2: To provide the additional details below
I have checked the logfile that was produced by the script. According to that, the error seems to come form the restarting of the virtual machine.
At 27: USER=, LOGNAME=matth
Fri May  3 11:38:01 AM HKT 2024: Backing up VM XGTERPNext
Fri May  3 11:38:02 AM HKT 2024: XGTERPNext's state is: "running".
Fri May  3 11:38:02 AM HKT 2024: Shutting down the VM XGTERPNext
Fri May  3 11:38:02 AM HKT 2024: 1 loop(s) waiting for the VM XGTERPNext to shut down. Current state is "running"
Fri May  3 11:38:07 AM HKT 2024: XGTERPNext's state is: "poweroff".
Fri May  3 11:38:23 AM HKT 2024: VM XGTERPNext has been copied from /home/matth/VMs/XGTERPNext/ to /home/matth/temp/
At 88: USER=, LOGNAME=matth
WARNING: Environment variable LOGNAME or USER does not correspond to effective user id.
Waiting for VM "XGTERPNext" to power on...
VM "XGTERPNext" has been successfully started.
Fri May  3 11:38:23 AM HKT 2024: VM is started up again
At 98: USER=, LOGNAME=matth

So I have added the suggested printout before and after that section as follows:
   echo "${cdt}: VM ${vm} has been copied from ${vmdir} to ${tempdir}" &>> $logfile
else
   err="not powered off"
   cdt=$(date)
   echo "${cdt}: Not exporting because the VM ${vm} is not powered off." &>> $logfile
fi
echo "At $LINENO: USER=$USER, LOGNAME=$LOGNAME" >> $logfile
if [[ $startup == 1 ]]; then
   vboxmanage startvm "$vm" --type headless &>> $logfile
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      err="starting up"
   else
      cdt=$(date)
      echo "${cdt}: VM is started up again" >> $logfile
   fi
fi
echo "At $LINENO: USER=$USER, LOGNAME=$LOGNAME" >> $logfile

When I run the script in the terminal manually, there is no warning message. When the script runs scheduled via crontab, the USER is empty, and therefore different from LOGNAME.
Also, this warning message only appeared since April 27, never before. I am not sure, but possibly I have run an update on April 26 and that has changed something?

Without seeing the crontab location (/etc/crontab or /var/spool/cron/$USER), the crontab entry AND the script, who can tell? Yes, you should investigate the message. Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.

Temporarily, insert set -x to turn on verbose shell execution, and find out where the error message is coming from. Also add printf "At %s: $USER=/%s/, LOGNAME=/%s/" $LINENO  $USER $LOGNAME at the beginning and elsewhere. Always paste your script into https://shellcheck.net, a syntax checker, or install shellcheck locally. Make using shellcheck part of your development process.

@waltinator I have added further details under EDIT 2. The warning only appears when the script is run via crontab, not when run manually in the terminal. Also the USER is empty when run via crontab.

After some more searching and trial and error, setting the env USER=$LOGNAME  in front of the script name in cron made the warning disappear.
So my crontab -e looks now like this.
24 2 * * * env USER=$LOGNAME /home/matth/buprod.sh

vs before
24 2 * * * /home/matth/buprod.sh

Thanks for all your replies and comments.

Ah OK so the issue is perhaps that on Linux, cron sets LOGNAME but not USER - apologies for the misdirection
